# How to remove an observation from a column that falls outside a desired range without leaving an NA

Tags: r

I am looking to remove multiple observations from one column within a dataframe based on their value without affecting the rest of the row.

```
df1=data.frame(c("male","female","male"),seq(1,30),seq(11,40))
names(df1) = c("col_a","col_b","col_c")
```

For example removing the values from column b that are below 5 or above 20 without affecting columns a or c. I am then looking to use this data for descriptive analysis and summaries.

Currently I am using this code to do the job:

```
df1$col_b[df1$col_b<5|df1$col_b>20] <- ""
df1$col_b<-as.numeric(df1$col_b)
```

However this creates NA values which get in the way of the analysis. Is there a way of doing this that does not create NA values or a quick way of removing them without affecting the row?

Comment: what do you propose to fill the "blanks" with that you create when you remove values?  Blanks are not valid numbers!

Comment: If I can't find a solution I am planning to replace these values with a negative number that can easily be recognised. Unfortunately a blank would be ideal!

Comment: In a numeric column, NA is a "blank".

Comment: BuckyO is it ok to edit your question to say *"How to ignore outliers in a column for subsequent analysis?"*

Comment: @smci I agree that your question better fits the answer but I think it's better to keep the original phrasing so that it is useful for others who are trying to do the wrong thing like I was.

Comment: @BuckyO yeah you're right, it's a chicken-and-egg unless you know that *'outlier'* is the word that fits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A numeric column can have normal values, `NA`, `Inf`, `-Inf` and `NaN`. But "empty" is not a possible value.

The reason for having `NA` is to mark that the value isn't available - seems exactly what you want! Using a negative number is just a more awkward way of doing the same thing - you'd have to remove all negative numbers before calculating `mean`, `sum` etc... You can do the same thing with `NA` - and that functionality is typically built into the functions: by specifying `na.rm=TRUE`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(col_a=c("male","female","male"),col_b=seq(1,30),col_c=seq(11,40))
df1$col_b[df1$col_b<5|df1$col_b>20] <- NA
sum(df1$col_b, na.rm=TRUE)    # 200
median(df1$col_b, na.rm=TRUE) # 12.5
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe what you really need is `mean(..., na.rm = TRUE)`. See `?mean`, let the existence of `NA` help you.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I have approved the other answer (which seems to have been submitted slightly after yours) as it described na.rm more fully.

Answer (score 1):

Use `subset`:

```
> df2 <- subset(df1, ! ( df1$col_b<5|df1$col_b>20) )
> df2$col_b <- as.numeric(df2$col_b)
> df2
    col_a col_b col_c
5  female     5    15
6    male     6    16
7    male     7    17
8  female     8    18
9    male     9    19
10   male    10    20
11 female    11    21
12   male    12    22
13   male    13    23
14 female    14    24
15   male    15    25
16   male    16    26
17 female    17    27
18   male    18    28
19   male    19    29
20 female    20    30
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have been more clear in my question. I am aiming to use the column within the original dataframe for the analysis without subsetting as the purpose of this process is to remove outliers both visually and for calculations of averages.

Comment: If you are using a data.frame there is no way to "remove values" from a column without making them NA. The entire point of having dataframes is to create a rectangualr structure with either a numberic of NA in columns of mode "numeric". So your question doesn't really parse on a meta level into the R language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking it your ultimate intent is "How to ignore outliers in a column for subsequent analysis?" 
You didn't say where the magic 5,20 range came from, nor what sort of analysis (mean/median/stdev, or something more complicated?).

You said: *"aiming to use the column within the original dataframe for the analysis without subsetting as the purpose of this process is to remove outliers both visually and for calculations of averages."*

If the magic 5,20 values came from a [quantile](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/quantile.html) (e.g. 5th-95th quantile, "middle 90th quantile"), you can compute arbitrary quantile values automatically with *`quantile(df1$col_b, c(0.05,0.95))`*. If you e.g. also want to see the median, pass the vector *`quantile(..., c(0.05,0.5,0.95))`*

Whereas if 5,20 is a known range, use the approach the others have shown you with logical indexing or subsetting to assign the outliers to NA. NA is your friend for analysis; it propagates into all calculations just like you'd want. NA is also your friend for plotting. Learn to love NA. Keep a copy of the original df (or just the original df$col_b) if you need to access the outlier values later.

If you want to experiment with distributions to see which one your data follows, see Ch 8 "Probability distributions" of http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

Here it all is in code:

```
#inrange <- function(x,a,b) { x>=a & x<=b }
inrange_else_NA <- function(x,minmax) { ifelse((x>=minmax[1] & x<=minmax[2]), x, NA) }

# If you want to save the original col_b and modify it in-place...
#df$col_b.orig <- df$col_b
# To exclude outliers outside a known range...
df$col_b_NAs <- inrange_else_NA(df$col_b, c(5, 20))
# ... or else to exclude outliers outside (say) middle 90th quantile
middle_90th_quantile <- as.vector(quantile(df$col_b, c(0.05,0.95)))
df$col_b_NAs <- inrange_else_NA(x,middle_90th_quantile)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer and the information on what to do in each case. In this case the 5-20 range was a known range.